# After Effects Script - inPoint from source footage

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I'm building a script. I'm trying to get the "in/outPoints" information of my layers. However, not from the layer in the composition, but from the layer window: **the in/outPoints from their source footage.**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYWP6.png]

(in the documentation it's only clear how to get them from the comp).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an attribute or method related to the inPoint of a footage item.